# How to get unique identifier of client server in Web API hosted in Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-worker-roles

I would like to get some unique identifier of client server in WebApi, which is hosted in Azure Worker Role.

I want to use it as identifier in internal database, which is consist of Table Storage to keep processed data from Worker Role.

For example, I have POST method in Web Api, which take some string and put it into Queue:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{            
      if (value != null)
      {
            Queue.Enqueue("requests", value);
      }
}
```

Then Worker Role process this string and save result to Table Storage

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");

    if(Queue.Count("requests") > 0)
    {

        String req = Queue.Dequeue("requests");
        //do some work with string, for example return length of string

        ResponseEntity re = new ResponseEntity(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server, req.Length.ToString());
        CloudTable table = Table.ReturnTable("responses");
        TableBatchOperation tbo = new TableBatchOperation();
        tbo.Insert(re);
        table.ExecuteBatch(tbo);
        Trace.TraceInformation("Done some work", "Information");
    }
}
```

At the end, client server can access to his result through his unique identifier from GET method in Web API:

```
  public string Get(string UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server)
  {
      string response = Table.GetResponseById("responses", UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server);
      return response;
  }
```

Do you have some ideas, how I can do this? Or should I do this another way to get UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server, so then client server can access his relative data?

Comment: If you want to get the Id of the current Web/Worker Role, you can use **RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id**.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `auto increment primary key` in Azure Storage Tables, you need to construct the key by yourself.

The Azure Storage Tables *primary key* consists of [*partition key* and *row key*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx).

It is important to know, that

- every partition key (as the name implies) puts the stored data in a different partition
- every row key is the *primary key* in any given partition
- you can then search by partition and row key combination

This is explained very good in article [What PartitionKey and RowKey are for in Windows Azure Table Storage](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/10/08/What-PartitionKey-and-RowKey-are-for-in-Windows-Azure-Table-Storage.aspx).

You need to analyze the data you want to store and decide what your key creation strategy will be.

Probably the best option would be a combination of the properties of the entity you want to save. An example could be found in this article [How to use Table storage from .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/).

Another possible solution would be to create a combination of *month-day* (as partition key) and *GUID* (as row key) - this way you will have different row keys per day, and every day will be stored in a single partition, for example:

```
11-17-2f0f97a8-c2f4-475e-b1d3-d1eab0f19739
11-17-b18f0932-11ff-49cd-9724-70494ea40f5b
```

If you store a value once a month, then better take year-GUID, so that you don't spread your data unnecessary on different partitions.

If the partitioning and searching is not important for your current project, then just use a timestamp, for example key *year-month-day* (as partition key) and *hour-minute-second-millisecond* (as row key):

```
2015-11-17-19-58-45-034
2015-11-17-19-59-52-349
```

Depending on how often you need to save (f.e. once per second), this strategy should generate always a unique key.

Comment: I am sorry, I have probably formulate my question wrong. My main problem is, that this UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server have to be seen also by client_server, so client server can access to his relative data in table, so I suggest, that UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_of_client_server should have some association with client server.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then you will end up overwriting the stored value (at least for the same session) on every request because the key will always be the same. Is this what you want? The *server unique data* will always be the same (on the same server), and the *client unique data* (for example the client IP) will change once in a while or resp. one proxy users will overwrite the stored data of another proxy user (because of the proxy more than one users will have the same IP).

Comment: Good point! I didnt think about that issue. But anyway I was thinking, that client server would like to have response immediately from Web API, so it would be trying GET method until it will get something meaningful (until WorkerRole pass process data to Table Storage).

Comment: So probably my problem should be solve by another way, but I have no idea how.